# Hibernate Interceptor - after load event

Tags: java, hibernate, solr, lucene, interceptor

Is there any event that occurs after an entity is loaded?
My goal is to add this entity to a Solr or Lucene index. The EmptyInterceptor OnLoad event occurs BEFORE an object is initialized. I want to handle an event AFTER the object properties are set. Is it possible with Hibernate Interceptors or with something else?

Comment: My simple one file example of hibernate listeners for spring boot (spring-boot-starter 1.2.4.RELEASE) http://stackoverflow.com/a/31725844/975169

Answer (score 5):

`@PostLoad` seems to do the job (see [community documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html)). If you annotate a method with this inside your entity, it should be triggered after the entity has been loaded.

Comment: I don't have access to entities classes (they are in core, my code is in a module). Sorry, I didn't mention this.

Comment: @DraggonZ Maybe you should edit your question with this? As your question is now, my answer is valid. If you edit your question, I will delete this answer.