# Hibernate 4 : setting a default value if query returns null

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm

I have a use case where i am mapping two tables to the same object.

In this object i have a string called source and I want to be able to set the table name or the database name to this variable.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

I have thought about iterating over my list and manually setting it but this has the potential to waste a fair chunk of time.

I appreciate this is somewhat of an odd request so this may be the only way but am hoping for a solution that maps the source variable when hibernate is mapping everything else.

Comment: _"I have thought about iterating over my list and manually setting it"_ Could you please explain this solution in more details?

Comment: so at the implementation of my dao (that has a seperate datasource than my other dao) i get my list of object via criteria.list() and then for(myObject current : myList){
current.setSource("tableOne");
}

Answer (score 1):

if i had understood correctly your issue , then your solution might be the MappedSuperClass , in which you must have an abstract class , which will have the common fields of the two tables and then you will extend that to the two entities you want , which will point to two different tables.
Check this [link](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/example-mappedsuperclass-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to achieve this with [Load listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487134/hibernate-interceptor-after-load-event) or [Interceptors](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html). In the listener/interceptor you can check [what the data source is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423930/how-to-retrieve-the-datasource-used-by-a-persistence-unit-programmatically) and populate the `source` field accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i ended up using a formula to map my variable to a select statement which was sufficient for what i needed.